# Python prime calculator - Not updating boolean value

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, primes

```
from sys import argv

def prime():
  for i in range(2,num):
      if num % i == 0:
          print(f"{num} can be divisible by {i}.")
          checker = False

num = int(input("Enter the number you want to check is prime: "))
checker = True

if num < 2:
    print(f"{num} is a prime number.")
elif num == 0:
    print(f"{num} is not a prime number.")
elif num > 0:
    prime()
    print(f"Is this number a prime - {checker}.")
else:
    print(f"Please write number larger than 0.")
```

Hello guys, I've just started to code and this is probably a really simple question. I want my code to either find the factors of a number or print if a number is a prime - but my boolean value in the "prime" function never updates to False. Not sure why!

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run this code, or does it print out `True`?

Comment: No errors, it just prints out True even if it's not a prime.

Comment: Write 'global checker' inside 'def prime' function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your `prime()` function is not 'updating' to `False` is because there is no [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) statement in the function.

With it, the function looks like this:

```
def prime():
  checker = True
  for i in range(2,num):
      if num % i == 0:
          print(f"{num} can be divisible by {i}.")
          checker = False
  return checker
```

And the updated code looks like this:

```
from sys import argv

def prime():
  checker = True
  for i in range(2,num):
      if num % i == 0:
          print(f"{num} can be divisible by {i}.")
          checker = False
  return checker


num = int(input("Enter the number you want to check is prime: "))

if num < 2:
    print(f"{num} is a prime number.")
elif num == 0:
    print(f"{num} is not a prime number.")
elif num > 0:
    is_prime = prime()
    print(f"Is this number a prime - {is_prime}.")
else:
    print(f"Please write number larger than 0.")
```

However, this isn't the only way to solve your problem: [it's not recommended and frowned upon by many programmers as bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil#19158418) - use the [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) statement (which looks like that's what you were trying to do originally).

With it, the function looks like this:

```
def prime():
  global checker
  for i in range(2,num):
      if num % i == 0:
          print(f"{num} can be divisible by {i}.")
          checker = False
```

And the updated code looks like this:

```
from sys import argv

def prime():
  global checker
  for i in range(2,num):
      if num % i == 0:
          print(f"{num} can be divisible by {i}.")
          checker = False


num = int(input("Enter the number you want to check is prime: "))
checker = True

if num < 2:
    print(f"{num} is a prime number.")
elif num == 0:
    print(f"{num} is not a prime number.")
elif num > 0:
    prime()
    print(f"Is this number a prime - {checker}.")
else:
    print(f"Please write number larger than 0.")
```

Comment: No worries - always happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime():
       global checker
       """ remaining logic as is"""
```

I think this would work.
   Sorry for format as I'm writing on phone.